# ALM excel add-in error while trying to map excel fields with ALM fields

Tags: ms-office, excel-2013, alm, hp-quality-center, defects

I am trying to upload test cases excel sheet to HP ALM. Below are the steps i followed to upload the sheet -

1. I chose the sheet to upload, opened it -> from toolbar -> clicked 'HP ALM Upload Add-in'
2. Clicked 'Log in to ALM' -> entered the ALM details along with the credentials, domain and project details and clicked Login

   3. I successfully completed the login process
   4. From excel sheet, i selected the test cases which i planned to upload to ALM
   5. Clicked 'Map Excel to ALM' i.e 'Mapping' icon
   6. From the window opened, ALM Excel Add-in-Field Mapping, clicked 'Entity' type drop down and selected 'Tests' option
   7. An error message as highlighted in the screenshot.

Correct me if i am wrong anywhere.
**

- Note :

** MS office 2013 is a 60 day trial version
ALM version 11.52

[image: ALM error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

See from the UI, you are using the excel add in version above 12.20.
excel add in (version above 12.20) does not support ALM version 11.52

you can get the 11.52 excel add in from the following page, 
as well as the supported ALM version for every excel add in.

https://hpln.hpe.com/contentoffering/microsoft-excel-add